# How can I set my desktop background folder to a shortcut?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, shortcuts, symbolic-link

I have a shortcut in my Pictures folder that points to a folder in my Dropbox containing my desktop backgrounds.

I would like for my desktop backgrounds to cycle through images in this folder. But when I click "Browse" In the "Desktop Background" settings page, the shortcut does not show up. I could set it directly to the folder in my Dropbox, but that defeats the purpose of having the shortcut there in the first place.

How can I set my desktop background folder to a shortcut?

Comment: You can create a directory junction using `mklink`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mklink` to make a directory junction:

`mklink /J Pictures\backgrouds Dropbox\backgrounds`

Comment: Exactly, you beat me to it. A junction or a symbolic link (`/D` switch) will do. It happens because when you create a shortcut to a directory you're not creating a symbolic link but a file (.lnk extension), hence it wouldn't appear when browsing. (can't vote up right now, have to wait until the new day)

Comment: Ah, coming from a linux background, I assumed that shortcuts were equivalent to soft links. So junctions are soft links, and shortcuts aren't built directly into the filesystem at all.